# Laraval Breeze: page or props is not defined in Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Goodmorning,

I'm building a web app with Laravel Breeze. Which uses Laravel, Vue.js and Inertia.js.

Im pretty far already, but I'm not able to use my data that I pass from my controller.

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;

use App\Models\Language;
use App\Models\Section;
use App\Models\SectionBlock;
use App\Models\BlockField;

class OverviewController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $languages = Language::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        $sections = Section::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        $sectionBlocks = SectionBlock::with('section')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        $blockFields = BlockField::with('sectionBlock.section')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        return Inertia::render('Overview', [
          'languages' => $languages,
          'sections' => $sections,
          'sectionBlocks' => $sectionBlocks,
          'blockFields' => $blockFields,
      ]);
    }
}

?>
```

Then my Overview.vue page looks like this:

```
<script setup>
import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue';
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

import { onMounted } from 'vue';

let languages = []; // Initialize an empty array or appropriate default value
onMounted(() => {
    // This function will run after the component is mounted and the data is available
    languages = $page.props.languages;
    console.log(languages);
});

</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Overview" />

    <AppLayout>

      <div>This is my main layaout for this page!</div>
      <pre>{{ JSON.stringify($page.props.languages, null, 2) }}</pre>

    </AppLayout>
</template>
```

However, when I use `$page.props.languages` inside of my template, it works perfectly. I can see the Languages output data on my page:
[image]

But in the console, I still get an error that $page is not defined:

```
Overview.vue:10 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: page is not defined
    at Overview.vue:10:5
```

Also when I use `props.languages`, `page.languages`.

Does anybody know how I use my props that are passed from my controller on my page?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, the problem here is how you use the `$page` object.

The `$page` object can only be used inside the `<template></template>` just like the `$props`, `$attrs` or `$data` in vue:

```
<template>
    {{ $page.props.languages }}
</template>
```

If you want to access the content of `$page` inside the `<script setup></script>` you need to use the `usePage()`.

```
<script setup>
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const languages = usePage().props.languages
</script>
```

you can also explicitly declare the data you pass from the controller as a props

```
<script setup >
defineProps({
    languages: Object,
    sections: Object,
    sectionBlocks: Object,
    blockFields: Object,
})
</script>

<template>
    {{ languages }}
</template>
```

[Controller Data using defineProps](https://inertiajs.com/pages)

[How to properly use the `$page` object](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data)